# Angular проверка email на наличия в базе

Tags: angular2, валидация, rxjs

У меня есть форма:

```
this.auteficationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.email, this.passwordValidator]),
  name: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required]),
  password: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
  secondPassword: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required])
}, {
  validator: MustMatch('password', 'secondPassword')
});
```

Питаюсь реализовать проверку наличия email в базе,но получаю ошибку:

```
error TS2740: Type 'Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscription': closed, _parent, _parents, _subscriptions, and 4 more.
```

**Реализация валидатора this.passwordValidator**

```
 passwordValidator(control: FormControl): Subscription {
    return this.authService.validateMail(control.value)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscibe))
      .subscribe(
        (e) => {console.log(e)}
      );

  }
```

this.authService идет на сервер и отправляет туда мыло,от сервера получаю ответ:

```
if(validation.length === 0){
    res.send(null);
  }else{
    res.send({uniq:true});
  }
```

Сколько пересмотрел примеров , никак не могу понять как реальзовать асинхронный валидатор на даную проверку!

Comment: массив, который идет вторым параметром в конструкторе `FormControl` - это синхронные валидаторы, ты туда передаешь ссылку на `passwordValidator`, это неверно. Почитай про `asyncValidators`, там не нужно делать подписку, за тебя это делает сам контрол

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 this.auteficationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.email], this.uniqueEmail.bind(this)),
  name: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required]),
  password: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
  secondPassword: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required])
}, {
  validator: MustMatch('password', 'secondPassword')
});
```

Валидатор:

```
uniqueEmail( control: AbstractControl ): Observable < ValidationErrors | null > {
   return  this.authService.validateMail(control.value)
      .pipe(map((res: string | null ) => {
          if( res !== null ) {
            return {
              invalidEmail: true
            };
          }
          return null;
        })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ты можешь перенести эти ошибки на сервер - имею в виду `invalidEmail: true` и `null`, то есть чтобы это присылал сервер через `res.json({ invalidEmail: true })`. Тогда на клиенте у тебя будет одна строчка - `return this.authService.validateMail(control.value);`. В этом случае клиент не будет брать на себя эту ответственность :)